# React navigation passing function to a stack navigator and then a header component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I have an expo react native app with react-navigation v3.

I am passing a signOut function from my main App to a header component of one of my stack navigators. I want to pass this header once so I don't want to add it to the navigationOptions for every screen.

I'm having trouble accessing the props in my MainStackNavigator and passing the function down to my component.

Main App

```
 render () {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <AppNavigator screenProps={{ signOut: this.signOut }}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

AppNavigator

```
export default createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator({
        // You could add another route here for authentication.
        // Read more at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html
        Main: MainStackNavigator,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Main'
    })
);
```

MainStackNavigator

```
export default createStackNavigator({
    Home: { 
        screen: HomeScreen, 
    }
},{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    defaultNavigationOptions : {
        headerTitle: <LogoTitle signOut={this.screenProps.signOut}/>,
        headerMode: 'screen',
    }
});
```

So when I am passing in the component LogoTitle, how do I access the screenProps at this point?

Comment: can you please check this out : 
`headerTitle: (props) => <LogoTitle signOut={props.screenProps.signOut}/>`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can access the `screenProps` in a `createStackNavigator` function. There's actually no point in passing it as `screenProps` because `screenProps` [are accessible in `screens/views` not `Navigators`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props). Moreover, there's [no `screenProps` prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html) in `AppNavigator`.

The correct way to do this would be through a `signOut` function that's defined in an `auth.js` file and accessible from everywhere. If you want to react to user's sign out then use `redux` and update the state and react to that update instead.

Comment: I think I'll give redux a go

Answer (score 2):

Passing something around in react is very typical task, before showing you the answer, we need to understand react doesn't like things injected out of nowhere, by default, you need to pass it to the children. Most of time, this means if you have a problem, you actually have a problem of parent-children relationship, either going up or down.

So in order to solve your problem in a bit generic way, you could consider passing a function that could change your `screenProps`, not `screenProps`, unless `screenProps` is always read only from the children point of view.

There's quite a bit way to achieve that. I'm only showing you one way via hooks

```
  const [props, setProps] = useState({ default props })
  return (
    <ChildrenComp onChange={setProps} />
  )
```

From now one, your children can always change props whenever they want via `onChange`.

And now we're back to the old things, which is passing `props` to children where you need them.

I'm not a fan of `redux` for simple problems, if you know your parent and your children, you should architect your code to facilliate that. If you really have to, you can go `useContext`, and really if you have no other choice, you can go `redux`. Don't use `redux` at the very beginning, it's not helpful for entry level programming especially when you are not 100% sure what is a `prop` in `react`.

Comment: I tried adding a hook but unfortunately it looks like I'll have to try something else as I still can't access the hook while inside creating the function. Think I will see what redux can offer.

Comment: Actually in terms of passing `props`, `redux` actually offers the similar thing. For example, you still need to implement an event/action to be dispatched via a `prop` similar to `onChange` in above example. Redux only allows you to make it global-variable like, but wouldn't change the nature of the problem.